# How do I update a UITableView on a timer while scrolling

Tags: swift, multithreading

My problem is very complicated to explain so I will do my best for explain it.

I'm doing a swift application with TableView. In this TableView, I have some data which are store in local (Dictionnary, Arrays, var, ...). 
So, in my TableView I'm refreshing this datas every 0.01 second. Then, when I scroll my TableView this refresh is stopped and I don't want it. I Want a "continue refresh".

Someone can explain how I can do it? I search on StackOverflow and the most answer is : the Thread. 
I understood Thread in C but it's very vague for me in Swift.
If you have an exercise for train multithreading in Swift you can post it !

Thanks for your time.

P.S: I can post some code but I don't think it's really necessary for my question.

**EDIT:**

There is the code for the timer and update

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, 
  selector:#selector(ViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, 
  repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer () {
  var j = 0
  for _ in rows {
    if (rows[j]["Activ"] as! Bool == true ) {
      rows[j]["timer"] = (rows[j]["timer"] as! Double + 0.01) as AnyObject
     }
    j += 1
  }
myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Show the code that does the timer and calls for the refresh.  The issue is that the table update and the scroll both need to be done in the main thread.  Even if you had another thread, it wouldn't help this.

Comment: @LouFranco Thanks for your answer. I have edit my question with code !

Comment: Updating your UI every `0.01` seconds makes no sense, since the screen cannot even update that fast. Your update frequency shouldn't be more than 1/30sec (30FPS).

Comment: What's your purpose of updating the UI every 0.01 second? It doesn't even looks logical!

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm doing a timer for Athletes, so I have to be very precise. And the problem is not here, this works fine

Comment: @pierreafranck updating the UI more frequently doesn't make your timer more precise and as I have told you, the screen cannot update at 100FPS, which you are trying to do, so it makes no sense. Moreover, `Timer` is not that accurate, if you need more precision, you should use a `Date` object.

Comment: @DávidPásztor ahh sorry you spoke about the frequency of update for my view? yes it's true I can go for 0.03 second

Comment: Also, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856788/4667835) about making a precise timer in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it happens because the `Timer` works in this same `DispatchQueue` as scrolling in the `UITableView`. You can solve this problem by using, for example, [AsyncTimer](https://github.com/Decybel07/AsyncTimer).

Comment: thanks for your answer dude. I know AsyncTimer but I want if possible not use pods for this project.

Comment: Then you can copy source cod from pod (MIT license)

Comment: Yes it's true. If I don't found anything I will do it ;) But I Think, a native method works for my need.

Comment: pod 'AsyncTimer' doesn't want to be install, is it normal?

Comment: @pierreafranck this is a young framework. You need update pod's repo. You can solve this problem using command `pod repo update` or `pod update`